# What are the possible values for $\dim(\ker(\lambda E_{8}-A)^2)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices

We know about the matrix $A\ \epsilon \ M_{8}(\mathbb{C}) $ with complex number $\lambda$ that $\dim(\ker(\lambda E_{8}-A))= 3$ and $\dim(\ker(\lambda E_{8}-A)^3)=6$.

What are the possible values for $\dim(\ker(\lambda E_{8}-A)^2)$?

Comment: What is $E_8$? What have you tried?

Comment: @Fimpellizieri E8 is the identity matrix  of a 8x8 Matrix In my mind it should be the values 3,4,5,6 as possibilities, As the kernel increases. But i am not sure if this is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct answer is that only dimensions $5$ and $6$ are possible.

What you are given is a linear operator $T$ such that $\dim(\ker(T))=3$ and $\dim(\ker(T^3))=6$, and the question is what values $\dim(\ker(T^2))$ can take. (That $T$ is described as $\lambda E_8-A$ is not really relevant.)

There are two relevant facts here about the sequence
$\dim(\ker(T^i))_{i \in\Bbb N}$ for any linear operator with finite dimensional kernel. The first is that the sequence is weakly increasing, the second that the sequence of differences $(\dim(\ker(T^{i+1}))-\dim(\ker(T^i)))_{i\in\Bbb N}$ is weakly *decreasing*. The first fact is clear from the inclusion $\ker(T^i)\subseteq\ker(T^{i+1})$ (since $T$ is linear, any vectors mapped to $0$ after $i$ times applying $T$ will still map to$~0$ when $T$ is applied once more).
The second fact is a bit more subtle: $T$ restricts for every$~i$ to a linear map $\ker(T^{i+1})\to\ker(T^i)$, which for $i>0$ induces a linear map between quotient spaces $f_i:\ker(T^{i+1})/\ker(T^i)\to\ker(T^i)/\ker(T^{i-1})$; I'll detail in just a second. The clue is that by construction $f_i$ will be *injective*, which by taking dimensions then gives the desired inequality $$\dim(\ker(T^{i+1}))-\dim(\ker(T^i))\leq \dim(\ker(T^i))-\dim(\ker(T^{i-1})).$$
Here's why. To construct $f_i$ one takes the composite map $\ker(T^{i+1})\to\ker(T^i)\to\ker(T^i)/\ker(T^{i-1})$ of the restriction of $T$ and the canonical projection on the quotient space, and remarks that its kernel contains $\ker(T^i)$, so that it (the composite map) induces a map on the quotient $\ker(T^{i+1})/\ker(T^i)$, which map is$~f_i$. But a bit more is true: the kernel of the composite map *equals* $\ker(T^i)$, and this means $f_i$ is injective. (Indeed, $f_i$ is just the isomorphism of $\ker(T^{i+1})/\ker(T^i)$ with the image of the composite map given by the first isomorphism theorem, followed by the embedding of this image as subspace of $\ker(T^i)/\ker(T^{i-1})$.)

Now in the concrete example with $d_i=\dim(\ker(T^i))$ for $i=1,2,3$ one gets $3=d_1\leq d_2\leq d_3=6$ from the first fact, and $d_2-d_1\geq d_3-d_2$ for the second fact, which becomes $2d_2\geq d_1+d_3=9$, and this leaves $d_2\in\{5,6\}$ as only possibilities.

To show that both possibilities occur, we can consider matrices$~A$ in Jordan normal form, looking only at Jordan blocks of for the eigenvalue$~\lambda$. To get $d_2=5$ one can take one such blocks of size at least$~3$, one of size$~2$ and one Jordan block of size$~1$. To get $d_2=6$ one can take $3$ Jordan blocks of size$~2$ for$~\lambda$. In both cases complete with Jordan blocks for other eigenvalues to get the required total size$~8$.

Jordan blocks can also be used to argue the second fact above: the blocks that contribute to $\dim(\ker(T^{i+1}))-\dim(\ker(T^i))$ also contribute to $\dim(\ker(T^i))-\dim(\ker(T^{i-1}))$, whence the inequality. Maybe that is what was intended in this exercise.

Comment: Multiple times some $i$ must be $1$, I guess. (Look for $T^{i+i}$.)

Comment: Right. 5 times. I must have been doing copy-paste. Thanks

Comment: Very nice answer; good that you corrected mine! Today I learned.